# Is it possible to use file system instead of actual Storage bucket in the cloud for development purposes (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, filesystems

I'm using `@google-cloud/storage` npm package to access bucket in GCP storage, everything works fine in production environment, but I would like to use local file system during local development, so that on the one hand any garbage won't appear in prod env on the other hand I won't impact other developers.

If this is not achievable what is the best way to use @google-cloud/storage during local development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some services have emulators:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators

It appears there's any emulator with limited (!) Cloud Storage functionally available through Firebase but I've not used it:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage

I'm unclear how you'd use the Cloud Storage emulator from a non-Firebase Storage SDK but it **should** work as it will implement the underlying API. Perhaps using `ClientOptions` to override the default service endpoint.